# Erro NetworkOnMainThreadException ao recuperar IP local do dispositivo

Tags: java, android

```
  String netAddress = "000.000.000.000";
        try
        {
            netAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        ipLocal.setText(netAddress);
```

Estou tentando recuperar meu ip local do dispositivo, coloquei o código acima no `onCreate` do meu `Activity`. Porém o `TextView` ipLocal só recebe o valor atribuído na inicialização da variável("000.000.000.000"). Meu dispositivo está conectado em minha rede wireless e eu importei as classes:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownServiceException;
import  java.net.UnknownHostException;
```

A mensagem de erro:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: net.ddns.tiyuri.networkutilities, PID: 22999
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.ddns.tiyuri.networkutilities/net.ddns.tiyuri.networkutilities.NuMain}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                   Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                      at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1599)
                      at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
                      at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
                      at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:851)
                      at net.ddns.tiyuri.networkutilities.NuMain.onCreate(NuMain.java:49)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7016)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 2):

Esta Exception aparaceu pois não é possível fazer operações de rede na Main Thread. Este throw é lançado apenas para Androids mais recentes que o Honeycomb. Porém a Google Android desencoraja a fazer isso em qualquer SDK.

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é criar uma Thread anônima na sua classe para cuidar destas operações de rede.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
      // sua operação de rede aqui
  }
}).start();
```

Outra forma é rodar em uma `AsyncTask` essas operações de rede

```
class RetrieveIP extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                try {
                    netAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                return netAddress;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                this.exception = e;

                return null;
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String netAddress) {
            // TODO: faça alguma coisa com seu return
            ipLocal.setText(address);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` quer dizer que você tentou acessar um recurso da rede na thread principal, o que causaria o bloqueio da UI.

Uma das formas de contornar isso é usando uma [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), que irá "transformar" sua operação síncrona em assíncrona.

```
public class GetAddressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        // Executado em background
        return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String address) {
        // Executado na thread de UI
        ipLocal.setText(address);
    }
}
```